# Html.lablefor to display empty instead of column name in case model.Columnname value is NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Am trying to display the value in razor view from model using the below code

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.testId, Model.testId)
```

Which displays the value of **testId** from DB  which renders as

```
<label for="LeadTimeText_DTD">12</label>
```

But incase the testID is null am getting the column name in label display

```
<label for="LeadTimeText_DTD">testId</label>
```

Where i want to display nothing like below in case if **testID** is null

```
<label for="LeadTimeText_DTD"></label>
```

is there any other way i do with HTML helper ? what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@Html.LabelFor` try using `@Html.DisplayFor` helper !

**EDIT** : Then i guess you just need to check your Model.testId value for null

```
@if(Model.Id != null)
{
    Html.LabelFor(m=>m.testId, Model.testId)
}
else
{
    Html.LabelFor(m=>m.testId, string.Empty)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No i need label as am using jquery to toggle between lable and textbox..any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

If u want Html helper only then you have just two options : 1. either use [Custom HtmlHelper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) 
or 2. use if/then condition for your Helper

Answer (score 0):

I created this extension method to force the label whether the label's value is null or not.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelForWithId<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var id = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));

        if (htmlAttributes != null)
        {
            var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes) as IDictionary<string, object>);
            tag.Attributes.Add("for", id);
            tag.Attributes.Add("id", id);
            tag.SetInnerText(helper.DisplayFor(expression).ToString());

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
        else
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<label id=\"{0}\" for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", id, helper.DisplayFor(expression)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using  @Html.DisplayFor may be good option and using custom html helper may be an over kill.

In MVC projects we use a lot custom extension method and one extension method I use quite often is the following

```
public static class CommonCustomExtensions
{
 public static string GetTrimValue(this string value)
        {
            // avoid the issue of string being null
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value.Trim();
        }
}
```

You can use the LabelFor html helper as follows to achieve same result and by the way this extension method is quite handy across controllers and helpers as it can handle null with grace

```
Html.LabelFor(m=>m.testId, Model.testId.GetTrimValue())
```